# Tsung : upload scenario with variables

Tags: tsung

I need some help with Tsung.

I would like to write a scenario in which a form is submitted. This form is used to upload a PDF document on the server. In addition, I need to "variabilize" some others fields like the document reference.

The Tsung documentation says to use the `contents_from_file` attribute. The inconvenience with that is I can't "variabilize".

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the susbtitution variable process inside the file defined in the contents_from_file attribute.

Comment: Hi Rodolphe. It didn't work with me because my file contains the "%%" string many times (certainly because of the PDF format). I replace "%%" with "@@" and now it's working. Thank you very much for your help !